# VMC tunnel crash

Tags: cloud-foundry, devkit, vmc

I'm trying to execute vmc tunnel but i get error 'ruby interpreter has stopped working' . Tryed to find what's the problem on the Internet but the only solution i saw was to upgrade ruby version to 1.9.3 , but I already have this version.

Thank you

Comment: How is this MySQL related? Show some code too.

Comment: I want to deploy a spring security web application that uses mysql. I've deployed war file but I also want to create manualy all necessary tables on cloudfoundry. I think on this stage there is no relation to the code itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me yesterday on Win7 using ruby 1.9.2p290. Ruby 1.9.3p194 failed with the same error you are getting.

Remember that the tunnel is a connection between the mysql client running on your local machine to the mysql service on cloudfoundry, so step 1 is making sure that your local mysql works, including your path so that vmc can easily find your client. Refer to the steps at http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html for details

Comment: The cloudfoundry engineering team has been notified of the 1.9.3p194 error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please execute the following commands and paste the output here?

```
ruby -v
vmc -v
```